# Trying to understand free body diagram

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

Please consider the following image:

[image]

Now I'm just trying to understand how exactly this thing is rotated...I'm looking at it exactly like on the image of the car...So the normal force is slightly bent because of the angle, but the angle seems to be on the opposite side from where it should be, I'd think it would be the lower corner, not the upper.

Comment: Consider the case $\beta \to 0$, it maybe easier to visualise why the diagram is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way: You have the standard $x$- and $y$-axes centered on the car. For a flat road, the positive $y$-axis points in the direction of the normal force. When we tip the road, you have to tip the axes as well. Since we tip the negative $x$-axis up $\beta$, that tips the positive $y$-axis to the right $\beta$. The normal force is making an angle with the positive $y$-axis as shown in the picture.